# Adding a class with javascript, not replace

Tags: javascript, css, class

I would like the ability to add a class to an element and not replace what classes are already there.

Here is my javascript so far:

```
function black(body) {
var item = document.getElementById(body);
    if (item) {
        item.className=(item.className=='normal')?'black':'normal';
    }
}
```

That piece of javascript replaces the existing classes with `black`. If the class already is `black` then it is changed to `normal`.

I would like to somehow combine the script above with the script below script, which adds a class, instead of replacing all existing classes.

```
var item = document.getElementById("body");
item.className = item.className + " additionalclass";
```

Comment: Maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList can help you. It's like jQuery but in plain javascript, but only works on very moder browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are several plain javascript functions you can use for manipulating class names in plain javascript.  It takes a little extra work in these functions to match whole class names only and avoid any extra spaces before/after classnames:

```
function removeClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    elem.className = str.replace(" " + cls + " ", " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

function addClass(elem, cls) {
    elem.className += (" " + cls);
}

function hasClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    var testCls = " " + cls + " ";
    return(str.indexOf(testCls) != -1) ;
}

function toggleClass(elem, cls) {
    if (hasClass(elem, cls)) {
        removeClass(elem, cls);
    } else {
        addClass(elem, cls);
    }
}

function toggleBetweenClasses(elem, cls1, cls2) {
    if (hasClass(elem, cls1)) {
        removeClass(elem, cls1);
        addClass(elem, cls2);
    } else if (hasClass(elem, cls2)) {
        removeClass(elem, cls2);
        addClass(elem, cls1);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to toggle between the `black` and `normal` classes without affecting any other classes on the specified object, you could do this:

```
function black(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if (obj) {
        toggleBetweenClasses(obj, "black", "normal");
    }
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/eR85c/

If you wanted to add the "black" class unless "normal" was already present, you could do this:

```
function black(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if (obj && !hasClass(obj, "normal")) {
        addClass(obj, "black");
    }
}
```

Comment: Such a great resource to have if for instance you're unable to use jQuery, or prototype.

Comment: The toggle code seems to be what I need, but having some trouble setting it up. This is the code I have now: `function black(body) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(body);
    if (obj) {
        toggleBetweenClasses(obj, 'normal', 'black');
    }
}`

Comment: My body html: `<body id="body" class="normal">` and my link: `<a href="javascript:black('body');">link</a>`

Comment: @davecave - It works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/eR85c/.  You'd have to show me your working page for me to know what error you have.

Comment: @davecave - FYI, you don't need an ID on the body tag.  You can always fetch it with `document.body`.

Comment: Error: `Reference Issue: Can't find variable: toggleBetweenClasses`  [Link to my page](http://quotes.littlethingsstudio.com)

Comment: @davecave - You have to include the code in my post for the various functions that manipulate classes.  In your case you need the code for: `toggleBetweenClasses()`, `removeClass()` and `addClass()`.  These are not built into the browser, you have to add them to your page in order to use them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15828/discussion-between-davecave-and-jfriend00)

Comment: Finally got it working after leaving the computer for a few minutes. Made a couple of changes to the html: http://jsfiddle.net/eR85c/3/   Original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/eR85c/

Comment: Hi, I think your remove function have the same problem you pointed out in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135162/adding-a-class-with-javascript-not-replace/12135605#comment16232732_12135605

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not going to add/remove/toggle classes that much, I would consider using something like the code below (instead of adding 2-3 functions like jfriend00's answer).

So here is the alternative for the ones that don't like to have many functions that will not use that frequently:

```
function toggle(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id), str, len;

    if (obj) {
        str = " " + obj.className + " ";
        len = str.length;

        str = str.replace(" normal ", " ");

        if (str.length != len) {
            str += " black";
        } else {
            str = str.replace(" black ", " ");

            if (str.length != len) {
                str += " normal";
            }
        }

        obj.className = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    }
}
```

It basically stores the length, tries to replace, checks if it removed the class (by comparing old and new lengths) then applies the necessary changes.

**Note:** it will toggle the classes perfectly with the condition that you should not have the two classes at the same time at the beginning.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eR85c/6/)**

Comment: I think this has a problem if the classname starts out `"one normal two"` because your replace makes it into `"onetwo"` and you end up with `'onetwo black"`.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right, it should be replaced with a space. Also I need to trim spaces (updating...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want or not because the answers here seems complicated to me...Anyway I needed to add class name without replacing the old one, so this is how I did it..

```
menu.children[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].**classList.add('resetAfter')**;
```

here i used `classList.add()` to append classes into anchor tag.